# Concatenating string properties of object created in function results in empty string?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am using the code provided [here](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/125942-vbscript-function-returning-multiple-values) as a template for accessing multiple class variable values (strings) defined by user inputs outside of a function, but the final result (the string variable `lptmstr`) is always empty; therefore, I need debugging assistance.

```
Class lptm
    public inputstr3
    public grpString1
    public inputstr4
    public grpString2
End Class 

Function lptmIn
    Set lptmIn = New lptm

    lptmIn.inputstr3  = InputBox("enter names")
    lptmIn.grpString1 = Split(inputstr3, ",")

    lptmIn.inputstr4  = InputBox("enter loss %")
    lptmIn.grpString2 = Split(inputstr4, ",")

    If UBound(lptmIn.grpString1) = UBound(lptmIn.grpString2) Then
    Else
        Call lptmIn
    End If
End Function

ublptm = UBound(lptmIn.grpString1)
For i=0 To ublptm
    lptmStr = lptmstr & lptmIn.grpString1(i) + lptmIn.grpString2(i)
Next
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.  You would have found the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your function `lptmIn` you call `Split` on the (undefined) variables `inputstr3` and `inputstr4` instead of the object properties `lptmIn.inputstr3` and `lptmIn.inputstr4`. Change this:

```
lptmIn.inputstr3 = inputbox("enter names")
lptmIn.grpString1 = split(inputstr3, ",")

lptmIn.inputstr4 = inputbox("enter loss %")
lptmIn.grpString2 = split(inputstr4, ",")
```

into this:

```
lptmIn.inputstr3 = inputbox("enter names")
lptmIn.grpString1 = split(lptmIn.inputstr3, ",")

lptmIn.inputstr4 = inputbox("enter loss %")
lptmIn.grpString2 = split(lptmIn.inputstr4, ",")
```

Plus, you need to assign the object created by the function call to a variable in your global code, otherwise you'll be calling the function `lptmIn` for every occurrence of `lptmIn` in the global code.

```
Set obj = lptmIn
ublptm = UBound(obj.grpString1)
For i=0 To ublptm
  lptmStr = lptmstr & obj.grpString1(i)  + obj.grpString2(i) 
Next
```

You may also want to refrain from recursively calling the function when the number of elements in the two arrays differs. Use a loop instead.

Modified code:

```
Function lptmIn
    Set o = New lptm

    Do
        o.inputstr3  = InputBox("enter names")
        o.grpString1 = Split(o.inputstr3, ",")

        o.inputstr4  = InputBox("enter loss %")
        o.grpString2 = Split(o.inputstr4, ",")
    Loop Until UBound(o.grpString1) = UBound(o.grpString2)

    Set lptmIn = o
End Function 

Set obj = lptmIn
For i=0 To UBound(obj.grpString1)
  lptmstr = lptmstr & obj.grpString1(i)  + obj.grpString2(i)
Next
```

As a side note, the variable and function names are *atrocious*. I strongly recommend picking more self-explanatory names.

Comment: I should have cleaned up the names for readability before posting the code, apologies.

Comment: For learning purposes, could you explain the necessity for `Set lptmIn = o` before the end of the function?

Comment: It's not a necessity per se, it's just cleaner to assign the created object to a local variable while you're working with it inside the function, and assign it to the function name once you actually return it.